# How to get the NET response of single system during performance testing using Load runner or other tools

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

There are multiple systems involved in my application in order to get the proper response to final system.

[image: Sample System Architecture]

Above image shows first the request will go from system 1 to system 2 and so on to system n. The final response will be visible in system 1. Here I want to know how we can get the "NET response time of one request from system 2  to system 3 or system 1 to system 2 and so on". I am a beginner in performance testing. Please let me know how we can achieve this.

Thank you so much!

Comment: There is a performance timing API coming from the W3C that may help in this for the future as well, https://w3c.github.io/server-timing/#dfn-server-timing-header-field

Answer (score 1):

APM tool Integration at System n through 1 (assuming your systems are supported by your APM tool), or log analysis of messages with timestamps indicating start and completion of an event.   As long as you have a unique correlating key in the logs you can then reconstruct timing records for various event types which are key to your understanding of performance in your ~n~ tier model